# org.hibernate.internal.util.collections.BoundedConcurrentHashMap$LIRSHashEntry leak memory

Tags: hibernate

I'm using springboot 3.0.5 and Hibernate 6.1.7

My project running on centos 7 with open-jdk 21.

After some hours the java thread cpu increase more than 100%.

I dumped the jvm heap and use MAT analyze it:

```
One instance of “org.hibernate.internal.util.collections.BoundedConcurrentHashMap$LIRSHashEntry” loaded by “org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @ 0x80000028” occupies 271,316,744 (74.66%) bytes. 

Keywords
org.hibernate.internal.util.collections.BoundedConcurrentHashMap$LIRSHashEntry
org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @ 0x80000028
```

The properties setted:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.query.in_clause_parameter_padding=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.query.plan_cache_max_size=32
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.query.plan_parameter_metadata_max_size=32
```

I don't know where the problem is.

Did anyone know about it?

Thanks a lot!

Use  MAT analyze the dump file

Comment: This class is an internal cache: it's purpose is to maintain references to a certain amount of objects (configurable), so it might look like a leak but it's by design. Unless you have better evidence of it actually holding on to references beyond the intended scope and size? The cpu utilization you report could indeed point to a leak, but it could also simply be a matter of not having enough memory for the load you have.

Comment: P.S. MAT is prone to report "large objects" as leaks but you should explode the graph to see where it leads. If even doing so you think it's retaining references that shouldn't be there, please open an issue on the Hibernate issue tracker ideally with a reproducer - we'll certainly have a look.

Comment: Thank you @Sanne. I just doubt it. Maybe the problem is not it. I will continue to find it.